# R plot with symbols and numbers in xlim

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to draw a plot with `xlim= c(seq(1:10),"p1","p2","p3")`.

See the input matrix(dat) with two columns below, where first column reprents a `seq(1:10)` and some of charater index and `y` represents corresponding either positive or negative numbers.

I have such more than 100 observations now. From the data, I would like to draw a plot to show all these observations with a fixed range of `xlim(1:10, p1,p2,and p3)` and `ylim c(-c,c)`, respectively.

If I use data.frame(dat) and `plot(dat$x,dat$y)`, y-axis is plotted with cumulative scale. But I would like to just plot all points individually like scatter plot instead of cumulative scale.

Any suggestions on this?

```
ind     AVG
1   -0.001918445
1   0.011974442
1   0.019024351
1   0.03726307
1   0.016309513
2   0.011794711
2   0.014253712
2   0.010653219
2   0.004265231
2   -0.002491867
3   -0.002591546
3   0.007201165
3   0.028188863
3   0.001293391
3   0.000132983
3   -0.030687808
3   -0.029407016
3   0.01271166
3   -0.045294952
3   -0.026326327
3   0.011403086
3   -0.050963337
3   -0.071073077
3   -0.390577703
4   -0.018628007
4   0.040197108
4   -0.025494461
4   -0.004010557
5   0.004878702
5   0.029016561
5   0.00042679
5   -0.006653925
5   -0.000635598
5   -0.0047732
5   -0.013822174
5   -0.018184046
5   -0.020757333
5   -0.011526818
5   0.026701501
p1  -0.016051634
p1  -0.019554239
p1  -0.05471509
p1  -0.067328741
p1  0.008895776
p1  -0.083768833
p1  -0.051836454
p1  0.003414714
p1  -0.086940334
p1  -0.123838462
p1  0.047389594
p2  -0.03621914
p2  -2.557102018
p2  -0.01016139
p2  0.005704343
p2  0.006728137
p2  0.027828334
p2  0.009036522
p2  0.000873728
p2  0.012612601
p2  0.005660987
p2  0.001389156
p2  -0.006263825
p2  -0.005124177
p2  -0.001244173
p2  0.019178429
p3  -0.004515657
p3  -0.007602823
p3  -0.032579185
p3  -0.032413178
p3  0.01039724
p3  -0.042059315
p3  -0.029409764
p3  0.003139373
p3  -0.054340919
p3  0.012265385
p3  -0.416087662
p3  0.031793228
p3  0.045973421
p3  -0.003058428
1   0.023589707
1   0.034300316
8   0.067181031
8   0.029577172
5   0.018463292
5   0.027671789
5   0.027456366
5   0.007938484
p1  0.001022771
p2  0.001847636
p3  0.019101029
2   0.050100828
2   0.012236761
2   0.001070529
2   -0.04911469
6   -0.048921924
6   0.024890427
p1  -0.079327173
p1  -0.03599943
p3  0.027655103
p3  -0.084695095
p3  -0.210153846
p2  -0.37156084
p2  -0.011561842
p2  0.083312089
```

Comment: How do you build your input matrix in R? What you wrote is not possible, you will probably have `"1", "2", "3", ..., "p1", "p2", "p3"`

Comment: Also, please post `dput(dat)` to give us some reproducible code.

Answer (score 0):

Please explain what sort of graph you are thinking of.  The plot parameter `xlim` takes exactly two values: the max and min range to plot.    Are you trying to plot each `dat$x` as a separate *category*, with the corresponding `dat$y` values plotted above that category?  If so, cheap and dirty
`plot(which(dat$x==c(1:10,"p1","p2","p3")), dat$y)`
may work (you'll have to read up on `plot` to learn how to print the category names along the x-axis).